# Can you escape an aircraft through the lavatory?

Tags: aircraft-design, airliner, commercial-aviation

In his book "Catch me if you Can", [Frank Abagnale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Abagnale#Alleged_escapes) claims he evaded arrest by removing a panel in the lavatory of a VC10, climbing through it and hence escaping out of the (taxiing) aircraft through a hatch.

Could this actually have been done?

*Plagiarism disclaimer: I found this question on another forum but didn't see a suitable answer there.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depends if there is any pressurized space behind the lav, and if there are any hatches in the pressure hull within that space.  On most airliners I would say it's not plausible, but looking at a VC10 cutaway it looks like the pressure hull extends all the way back to the tail cone, to a small bulkhead under the rudder, and there is a hatch forward of that.  *IF* the mechanism can be worked from the inside, the hatch could be opened when taxiing because the hull is vented to atmosphere at that point.  It's possible that a panel in the aft most lav would expose a service hatch in the non-pressurized bulkhead where the engine support beam goes across, which would lead to the tail cone hatch.

Lot of ifs there, but from what I can see I wouldn't rule it out.

https://www.flickr.com/photos/27417638@N07/7408063162

Comment: If it's plausible, would that really only be if he got lucky and was aboard a VC10? Or would that possibly have worked in other common passenger aircraft?